# Table in an overflow DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is in a DIV with `overflow: auto` :

HTML:

```
<div id="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In total there are 6 TH tags and 6 TD tags

CSS:

```
div#table
{
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}

div#table table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

The overflow ensures that there is a horizontal scroll bar on the DIV so that the full table can be viewed.

I also specified padding on the DIV in the hope that the scroll bar and table are not positioned on the edges of the DIV - however this bit isn't working.

So basically what I want is for there to be padding around the DIV and the overflown content should not be touching the right edge of the DIV. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Can we see the rest of your css (the part that applies to these elements?)

Comment: how about simply adding a last <td> element in each row that is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this? http://jsbin.com/iseda3
if yes you can use the following code:

**html**

```
<div id="table">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div#table {
    background:#09F;
    width:150px;
}
div#table div {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 15px;
}
div#table table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to wrap your table in one further `<div>` element that has the required padding within it.  Your table would then fit within that element but would still be subject to the parent container's overflow.

```
<div id="table">
  <div style="padding: 1em;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider making a container div that has the padding, and then put the div with id `table` inside of that larger div.

```
div#tableHolder
{
    padding: 15px;
}
div#table
{
    overflow: auto;
}

div#table table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```